# Hidden label does not visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to unvisible some text and visible some label. after click bottom my text will disappear but my label does not show.
What should I do?

```
<body>
        <div id="middle">
            <div id="left">
            </div >
            <div id="m">
            Name: <input type="text" name="y1"><br />
            Family: <input type="text" name="y1"><br />
            Phone: <input type="text" name="y1"><br />

            <label style="display: none "  name="y2" >A </label>
            <label  style="display: none " name="y2" >B </label>
            <label style="display: none " name="y2" >C </label>
            <button  onclick="myFunction()">Hide elements</button>

            <script>
            function myFunction() {
              var x = document.getElementsByName("y1");
              for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
              }
              var x = document.getElementsByName("y2");
              for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "visible !important"; 
              }
            }
            </script>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: `visible` is not a valid `display` value. Use `initial` to set it back to what it was originally. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: `x[i].style.display = "inline";`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: I also would like to inform you that in SO you can accept one answer only. If you try to accept a 2nd answer, the accept mark from the first one will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the [`display` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) doesn't have a value of `visible`. `visible` is for the `visibility` property. For `display`, you'd set it to `inline` for a label.

Having said that, you aren't using the [`label` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) correctly in the first place. It's meant to be associated with an form field, which you aren't doing, so you should use `span` elements instead.

Also, don't use inline styles or event handlers. Use CSS classes and do all your scripting in the `script`.

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
            Name: <input type="text" name="y1" class="hidable"><br>
            Family: <input type="text" name="y2" class="hidable"><br>
            Phone: <input type="text" name="y3" class="hidable"><br>

            <span class="hidden y2">A</span>
            <span class="hidden y2">B</span>
            <span class="hidden y2">C</span>
            <button>Hide elements</button>

            <script>
              // Get the inputs and spans into their own Arrays
              let inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input.hidable"));
              let spans = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("span.y2")); 
              
              // Set up the click event handler in JavaScript, not in HTML
              document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", hideShow);
              
              function hideShow() {
                // Loop over the inputs
                inputs.forEach(function(input){
                  input.classList.add("hidden"); // Hide the input
                });
                
                // Loop over the spans
                spans.forEach(function(input){
                  input.classList.remove("hidden"); // Show the span
                });
              }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("y1");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  var x = document.getElementsByName("y2");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="middle">
  <div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="m">
    Name: <input type="text" name="y1"><br /> 
    Family: <input type="text" name="y1"><br /> 
    Phone: <input type="text" name="y1"><br />

    <label style="display: none " name="y2">A </label>
    <label style="display: none " name="y2">B </label>
    <label style="display: none " name="y2">C </label>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Hide elements</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

If it is, please note that display property has several possible values besides `inline`. Please read about CSS Layout. Here is a link to get you started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout